# PowerShell retrieve MS Graph 3rd level data return non-json result

Tags: json, powershell, office365, hashtable, microsoft-graph-api

I got a PS script to retrieve an AuditLog event from MS Graph. The script code is below. It gets the event details in JSON format.

```
    # Create Authentication Token for MS Graph
Function GetAuthToken
{
    param
        (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $TenantName
        )
    Import-Module Azure
    $clientId = "ef9bcdf0-a675-4cd5-9ec3-fa549f9ee4cf" 
    $redirectUri      = "https://RedirectURI.com" 
    $resourceAppIdURI = "https://graph.microsoft.com"
    $authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantName"
    $authContext = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext" -ArgumentList $authority
    $Credential = Import-Clixml -Path "C:\MIMA\tom_admin_cred.xml"
    $AADCredential = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserCredential" -ArgumentList $credential.UserName,$credential.Password
    $authResult = $authContext.AcquireToken($resourceAppIdURI, $clientId,$AADCredential)
    return $authResult
}

Function Get-aAuditEvent
{
    param
        (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $Tenant
        )

    if($Version -eq $null) {$Version='Beta'}
    #------Get the authorization token------#
    $token = GetAuthToken -TenantName $tenant 

    #------Building Rest Api header with authorization token------#
    $authHeader = @{
        'Content-Type'='application\json'
        'Authorization'=$token.CreateAuthorizationHeader()
        }

    $uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditlogs/directoryAudits/Directory_3WOOD_3967500"
    # $uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditlogs/directoryAudits"
    Try {
            $results = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri –Headers $authHeader –Method Get 
            $results |ConvertTo-Json -depth 4
        }
    catch{
        Write-Host "Error while retrieving report!" -ForegroundColor red
        $auditReports = $_.Exception.Response
        }    
}


Get-aAuditEvent -Tenant "contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
```

The result of the code is as below. Notice the content of "modifiedProperties" is not in JSON format? It seems somehow the value of this property has converted to hashtable. However, I tried to put this value into a hashtable and it couldn't parse it properly anyway. Maybe because "newValue" is too long for a hash table?

```
    {
    "@odata.context":  "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#auditLogs/directoryAudits/$entity",
    "id":  "Directory_3WOOD_3967500",
    "category":  "Core Directory",
    "correlationId":  "559450b1-d1e8-4020-a420-4c3c6234ba44",
    "result":  "success",
    "resultReason":  "",
    "activityDisplayName":  "Update user",
    "activityDateTime":  "2018-10-13T14:57:33.328183Z",
    "loggedByService":  null,
    "initiatedBy":  {
                        "app":  null,
                        "user":  {
                                    "id":  "9327abf7-93ea-4007-a15c-9b77b5360cc9",
                                    "displayName":  null,
                                    "userPrincipalName":  "tom-admin@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
                                    "ipAddress":  "\u003cnull\u003e"
                                }
                    },
    "targetResources":  [
                            {
                                "@odata.type":  "#microsoft.graph.targetResourceUser",
                                "id":  "2a58e6ca-2207-4fc0-ba5d-210cd5de25dc",
                                "displayName":  null,
                                "userPrincipalName":  "tom.chen@contoso.com",
                                "modifiedProperties":  [
                                                        "@{displayName=AssignedLicense; oldValue=[]; newValue=[\"[SkuName=ENTERPRISEPACK, AccountId=cdc4b90d-7fa9-4a12-8d58-c2872266673c, SkuId=6fd2c87f-b296-42f0-b197-1e91e994b900, DisabledPlans=[]]\"]}",
                                                        "@{displayName=AssignedPlan; oldValue=[]; newValue=[{\"SubscribedPlanId\":\"f0e58183-18c1-4fa6-939b-e78d050533b6\",\"ServiceInstance\":\"To-Do/NA001\",\"CapabilityStatus\":0,\"AssignedTimestamp\":\"2018-10-13T14:
57:33.1683839Z\",\"InitialState\":null,\"Capability\":null,\"ServicePlanId\":\"c87f142c-d1e9-4363-8630-aaea9c4d9ae5\"},{\"SubscribedPlanId\":\"ea0d7e34-84a0-4329-910a-f38d7d4f2c00\",\"ServiceInstance\":\"OfficeForms/NA001\",\"CapabilityStatus\":0,\"AssignedTimestamp\":\"
2018-10-13T14:57:33.1683839Z\",\"InitialState\":null,\"Capability\":null,\"ServicePlanId\":\"2789c901-c14e-48ab-a76a-be334d9d793a\"},{\"SubscribedPlanId\":\"0defa810-1846-4ebf-8c01-4b72f9dbec2c\",\"ServiceInstance\":\"MicrosoftStream/NA001\",\"CapabilityStatus\":0,\"Assi
gnedTimestamp\":\"2018-10-13T14:57:33.1683839Z\",\"InitialState\":null,\"Capability\":null,\"ServicePlanId\":\"9e700747-8b1d-45e5-ab8d-ef187ceec156\"},{\"SubscribedPlanId\":\"e56c4814-73b8-4a12-ac13-bd2236e1c61c\",\"ServiceInstance\":\"Deskless/NA001\",\"CapabilityStatus
\":0,\"AssignedTimestamp\":\"2018-10-13T14:57:33.1683839Z\",\"InitialState\":null,\"Capability\":null,\"ServicePlanId\":\"8c7d2df8-86f0-4902-b2ed-a0458298f3b3\"},{\"SubscribedPlanId\":\"ef68b42e-5730-41b8-b119-a78dd199cd39\",\"ServiceInstance\":\"ProcessSimple/NA001\",\"
CapabilityStatus\":0,\"AssignedTimestamp\":\"2018-10-13T14:57:33.1683839Z\",\"InitialState\":null,\"Capability\":null,\"ServicePlanId\":\"76846ad7-7776-4c40-a281-a386362dd1b9\"},{\"SubscribedPlanId\":\"d69c693a-dfc8-49f8-9bd2-68b570bc3dd8\",\"ServiceInstance\":\"PowerApp
sService/NA001\",\"CapabilityStatus\":0,\"AssignedTimestamp\":\"2018-10-13T14:57:33.1683839Z\",\"InitialState\":null,\"Capability\":null,\"ServicePlanId\":\"c68f8d98-5534-41c8-bf36-22fa496fa792\"},{\"SubscribedPlanId\":\"b3e7a5a5-bfae-4ae6-887c-ce9665de0610\",\"ServiceIn
stance\":\"TeamspaceAPI/NA001\",\"CapabilityStatus\":0,\"AssignedTimestamp\":\"2018-10-13T14:57:33.1683839Z\",\"InitialState\":null,\"Capability\":null,\"ServicePlanId\":\"57ff2da0-773e-42df-b2af-ffb7a2317929\"},{\"SubscribedPlanId\":\"c9dbc746-7d1d-449f-9a2c-f80c99df11f
2\",\"ServiceInstance\":\"ProjectWorkManagement/PROD_OC_Org_Ring_010\",\"CapabilityStatus\":0,\"AssignedTimestamp\":\"2018-10-13T14:57:33.1683839Z\",\"InitialState\":null,\"Capability\":null,\"ServicePlanId\":\"b737dad2-2f6c-4c65-90e3-ca563267e8b9\"},{\"SubscribedPlanId\
":\"6aa67dd9-afd1-47c4-b81f-065ba3495692\",\"ServiceInstance\":\"Sway/NA001\",\"CapabilityStatus\":0,\"AssignedTimestamp\":\"2018-10-13T14:57:33.1683839Z\",\"InitialState\":null,\"Capability\":null,\"ServicePlanId\":\"a23b959c-7ce8-4e57-9140-b90eb88a9e97\"},{\"Subscribed
PlanId\":\"6d4d99fc-d0e1-4350-a4da-cb79cadd739e\",\"ServiceInstance\":\"YammerEnterprise/NA009\",\"CapabilityStatus\":0,\"AssignedTimestamp\":\"2018-10-13T14:57:33.1683839Z\",\"InitialState\":null,\"Capability\":null,\"ServicePlanId\":\"7547a3fe-08ee-4ccb-b430-5077c50416
53\"},{\"SubscribedPlanId\":\"ac1fca1c-7d64-476c-b1f8-1c336ccac213\",\"ServiceInstance\":\"RMSOnline/AP\",\"CapabilityStatus\":0,\"AssignedTimestamp\":\"2018-10-13T14:57:33.1683839Z\",\"InitialState\":null,\"Capability\":null,\"ServicePlanId\":\"bea4c11e-220a-4e6d-8eb8-8
ea15d019f90\"},{\"SubscribedPlanId\":\"2cc87a99-6c05-4bf2-a8a7-4a75e26a6afd\",\"ServiceInstance\":\"MicrosoftOffice/NorthAmerica\",\"CapabilityStatus\":0,\"AssignedTimestamp\":\"2018-10-13T14:57:33.1683839Z\",\"InitialState\":null,\"Capability\":null,\"ServicePlanId\":\"
43de0ff5-c92c-492b-9116-175376d08c38\"},{\"SubscribedPlanId\":\"97006162-e810-4814-98e7-3ae3745b28bc\",\"ServiceInstance\":\"MicrosoftCommunicationsOnline/Instance04-S\",\"CapabilityStatus\":0,\"AssignedTimestamp\":\"2018-10-13T14:57:33.1683839Z\",\"InitialState\":null,\
"Capability\":null,\"ServicePlanId\":\"0feaeb32-d00e-4d66-bd5a-43b5b83db82c\"},{\"SubscribedPlanId\":\"10985cf4-2206-4e47-9910-426586912b1a\",\"ServiceInstance\":\"SharePoint/SPOS0017\",\"CapabilityStatus\":0,\"AssignedTimestamp\":\"2018-10-13T14:57:33.1683839Z\",\"Initi
alState\":null,\"Capability\":null,\"ServicePlanId\":\"e95bec33-7c88-4a70-8e19-b10bd9d0c014\"},{\"SubscribedPlanId\":\"e0592405-cc57-4152-8cc0-3f8e5651e47d\",\"ServiceInstance\":\"SharePoint/SPOS0017\",\"CapabilityStatus\":0,\"AssignedTimestamp\":\"2018-10-13T14:57:33.16
83839Z\",\"InitialState\":null,\"Capability\":null,\"ServicePlanId\":\"5dbe027f-2339-4123-9542-606e4d348a72\"},{\"SubscribedPlanId\":\"552916d8-55f1-44be-a7e1-9a56b8086a9b\",\"ServiceInstance\":\"exchange/apcprd03-001-01\",\"CapabilityStatus\":0,\"AssignedTimestamp\":\"2
018-10-13T14:57:33.1683839Z\",\"InitialState\":null,\"Capability\":null,\"ServicePlanId\":\"efb87545-963c-4e0d-99df-69c6916d9eb0\"}]}",
                                                        "@{displayName=Included Updated Properties; oldValue=; newValue=\"AssignedLicense, AssignedPlan\"}",
                                                        "@{displayName=TargetId.UserType; oldValue=; newValue=\"Member\"}"
                                                    ]
                            }
                        ],
    "additionalDetails":  [
                            {
                                "key":  "UserType",
                                "value":  "Member"
                            }
                        ]
}
```

This is very odd, as when I retrieve the same event from MS Graph Explorer, I get different result, which is all in proper JSON foramt. Below is the output from MS Graph Explorer. As you can see, the "modifiedProperties" pair is still presented in JSON format.

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#auditLogs/directoryAudits/$entity",
    "id": "Directory_3WOOD_3967500",
    "category": "Core Directory",
    "correlationId": "559450b1-d1e8-4020-a420-4c3c6234ba44",
    "result": "success",
    "resultReason": "",
    "activityDisplayName": "Update user",
    "activityDateTime": "2018-10-13T14:57:33.328183Z",
    "loggedByService": null,
    "initiatedBy": {
        "app": null,
        "user": {
            "id": "9327abf7-93ea-4007-a15c-9b77b5360cc9",
            "displayName": null,
            "userPrincipalName": "tom-admin@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
            "ipAddress": "<null>"
        }
    },
    "targetResources": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.targetResourceUser",
            "id": "2a58e6ca-2207-4fc0-ba5d-210cd5de25dc",
            "displayName": null,
            "userPrincipalName": "tom.chen@contoso.com",
            "modifiedProperties": [
                {
                    "displayName": "AssignedLicense",
                    "oldValue": "[]",
                    "newValue": "[\"[SkuName=ENTERPRISEPACK, AccountId=cdc4b90d-7fa9-4a12-8d58-c2872266673c, SkuId=6fd2c87f-b296-42f0-b197-1e91e994b900, DisabledPlans=[]]\"]"
                },
                {
                    "displayName": "AssignedPlan",
                    "oldValue": "[]",
                    "newValue": "[{\"SubscribedPlanId\":\"f0e58183-18c1-4fa6-939b-e78d050533b6\",\"ServiceInstance\":\"To-Do/NA001\",\"CapabilityStatus\":0,\"AssignedTimestamp\":\"2018-10-13T14:57:33.1683839Z\",\"InitialState\":null,\"Capability\":null,\"ServicePlanId\":\"c87f142c-d1e9-4363-8630-aaea9c4d9ae5\"},{\"SubscribedPlanId\":\"ea0d7e34-84a0-4329-910a-f38d7d4f2c00\",\"ServiceInstance\":\"OfficeForms/NA001\",\"CapabilityStatus\":0,\"AssignedTimestamp\":\"2018-10-13T14:57:33.1683839Z\",\"InitialState\":null,\"Capability\":null,\"ServicePlanId\":\"2789c901-c14e-48ab-a76a-be334d9d793a\"},{\"SubscribedPlanId\":\"0defa810-1846-4ebf-8c01-4b72f9dbec2c\",\"ServiceInstance\":\"MicrosoftStream/NA001\",\"CapabilityStatus\":0,\"AssignedTimestamp\":\"2018-10-13T14:57:33.1683839Z\",\"InitialState\":null,\"Capability\":null,\"ServicePlanId\":\"9e700747-8b1d-45e5-ab8d-ef187ceec156\"},{\"SubscribedPlanId\":\"e56c4814-73b8-4a12-ac13-bd2236e1c61c\",\"ServiceInstance\":\"Deskless/NA001\",\"CapabilityStatus\":0,\"AssignedTimestamp\":\"2018-10-13T14:57:33.1683839Z\",\"InitialState\":null,\"Capability\":null,\"ServicePlanId\":\"8c7d2df8-86f0-4902-b2ed-a0458298f3b3\"},{\"SubscribedPlanId\":\"ef68b42e-5730-41b8-b119-a78dd199cd39\",\"ServiceInstance\":\"ProcessSimple/NA001\",\"CapabilityStatus\":0,\"AssignedTimestamp\":\"2018-10-13T14:57:33.1683839Z\",\"InitialState\":null,\"Capability\":null,\"ServicePlanId\":\"76846ad7-7776-4c40-a281-a386362dd1b9\"},{\"SubscribedPlanId\":\"d69c693a-dfc8-49f8-9bd2-68b570bc3dd8\",\"ServiceInstance\":\"PowerAppsService/NA001\",\"CapabilityStatus\":0,\"AssignedTimestamp\":\"2018-10-13T14:57:33.1683839Z\",\"InitialState\":null,\"Capability\":null,\"ServicePlanId\":\"c68f8d98-5534-41c8-bf36-22fa496fa792\"},{\"SubscribedPlanId\":\"b3e7a5a5-bfae-4ae6-887c-ce9665de0610\",\"ServiceInstance\":\"TeamspaceAPI/NA001\",\"CapabilityStatus\":0,\"AssignedTimestamp\":\"2018-10-13T14:57:33.1683839Z\",\"InitialState\":null,\"Capability\":null,\"ServicePlanId\":\"57ff2da0-773e-42df-b2af-ffb7a2317929\"},{\"SubscribedPlanId\":\"c9dbc746-7d1d-449f-9a2c-f80c99df11f2\",\"ServiceInstance\":\"ProjectWorkManagement/PROD_OC_Org_Ring_010\",\"CapabilityStatus\":0,\"AssignedTimestamp\":\"2018-10-13T14:57:33.1683839Z\",\"InitialState\":null,\"Capability\":null,\"ServicePlanId\":\"b737dad2-2f6c-4c65-90e3-ca563267e8b9\"},{\"SubscribedPlanId\":\"6aa67dd9-afd1-47c4-b81f-065ba3495692\",\"ServiceInstance\":\"Sway/NA001\",\"CapabilityStatus\":0,\"AssignedTimestamp\":\"2018-10-13T14:57:33.1683839Z\",\"InitialState\":null,\"Capability\":null,\"ServicePlanId\":\"a23b959c-7ce8-4e57-9140-b90eb88a9e97\"},{\"SubscribedPlanId\":\"6d4d99fc-d0e1-4350-a4da-cb79cadd739e\",\"ServiceInstance\":\"YammerEnterprise/NA009\",\"CapabilityStatus\":0,\"AssignedTimestamp\":\"2018-10-13T14:57:33.1683839Z\",\"InitialState\":null,\"Capability\":null,\"ServicePlanId\":\"7547a3fe-08ee-4ccb-b430-5077c5041653\"},{\"SubscribedPlanId\":\"ac1fca1c-7d64-476c-b1f8-1c336ccac213\",\"ServiceInstance\":\"RMSOnline/AP\",\"CapabilityStatus\":0,\"AssignedTimestamp\":\"2018-10-13T14:57:33.1683839Z\",\"InitialState\":null,\"Capability\":null,\"ServicePlanId\":\"bea4c11e-220a-4e6d-8eb8-8ea15d019f90\"},{\"SubscribedPlanId\":\"2cc87a99-6c05-4bf2-a8a7-4a75e26a6afd\",\"ServiceInstance\":\"MicrosoftOffice/NorthAmerica\",\"CapabilityStatus\":0,\"AssignedTimestamp\":\"2018-10-13T14:57:33.1683839Z\",\"InitialState\":null,\"Capability\":null,\"ServicePlanId\":\"43de0ff5-c92c-492b-9116-175376d08c38\"},{\"SubscribedPlanId\":\"97006162-e810-4814-98e7-3ae3745b28bc\",\"ServiceInstance\":\"MicrosoftCommunicationsOnline/Instance04-S\",\"CapabilityStatus\":0,\"AssignedTimestamp\":\"2018-10-13T14:57:33.1683839Z\",\"InitialState\":null,\"Capability\":null,\"ServicePlanId\":\"0feaeb32-d00e-4d66-bd5a-43b5b83db82c\"},{\"SubscribedPlanId\":\"10985cf4-2206-4e47-9910-426586912b1a\",\"ServiceInstance\":\"SharePoint/SPOS0017\",\"CapabilityStatus\":0,\"AssignedTimestamp\":\"2018-10-13T14:57:33.1683839Z\",\"InitialState\":null,\"Capability\":null,\"ServicePlanId\":\"e95bec33-7c88-4a70-8e19-b10bd9d0c014\"},{\"SubscribedPlanId\":\"e0592405-cc57-4152-8cc0-3f8e5651e47d\",\"ServiceInstance\":\"SharePoint/SPOS0017\",\"CapabilityStatus\":0,\"AssignedTimestamp\":\"2018-10-13T14:57:33.1683839Z\",\"InitialState\":null,\"Capability\":null,\"ServicePlanId\":\"5dbe027f-2339-4123-9542-606e4d348a72\"},{\"SubscribedPlanId\":\"552916d8-55f1-44be-a7e1-9a56b8086a9b\",\"ServiceInstance\":\"exchange/apcprd03-001-01\",\"CapabilityStatus\":0,\"AssignedTimestamp\":\"2018-10-13T14:57:33.1683839Z\",\"InitialState\":null,\"Capability\":null,\"ServicePlanId\":\"efb87545-963c-4e0d-99df-69c6916d9eb0\"}]"
                },
                {
                    "displayName": "Included Updated Properties",
                    "oldValue": null,
                    "newValue": "\"AssignedLicense, AssignedPlan\""
                },
                {
                    "displayName": "TargetId.UserType",
                    "oldValue": null,
                    "newValue": "\"Member\""
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "additionalDetails": [
        {
            "key": "UserType",
            "value": "Member"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `ConvertTo-Json -depth 10`?

Comment: Ye. I already tried with different depth. Still getting the same result.

Comment: Try this. ConvertTo-Json $results.

Comment: Thanks Bruce, but same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact both results (via PowerShell and Microsoft Graph Explorer) seems to be identical (except some formatting differences).

In both cases a *valid* JSON value is returned.

Now comes the turn of `oldValue` and `newValue` property values.
According to documentation, [`modifiedProperty` property](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/modifiedproperty) of `targetResource` resource
returns the collection of `name`, `old value` and `new value` which represented in JSON format like this:

```
{
  "displayName": "String",
  "newValue": "String",
  "oldValue": "String"
}
```

meaning `newValue` and `oldValue` return the converted to `string` values.

**Example**

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#auditLogs/directoryAudits/$entity",
    "id": "Directory_GIRJA_107870298",
    //...
    "targetResources": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.targetResourceGroup",
            //...  
            "modifiedProperties": [
                {
                    "displayName": "foo",
                    "oldValue": "[]",
                    "newValue": "[\"bar\"]"
                },
                //...
                {
                    "displayName": "json_value",
                    "oldValue": null,
                    "newValue": "[{\"first_name\":\"Jon\",\"last_name\":\"Doe\"}]"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "additionalDetails": []
}
```

> **Note:** pay attention to the second `modifiedProperty` entry `newValue` property, which represents JSON value and is returned as a string: `{"first_name":"Jon","last_name":"Doe"}`

Using the following example `newValue` could be converted to JSON:

```
$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditLogs/directoryAudits/{directory-id}"
$results = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Method Get
$results.targetResources | Select -ExpandProperty modifiedProperties | Select -ExpandProperty newValue | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Comment: Thanks Vadim! Your solution works better than mine as it further segragates the newValue data. However, I do have notice the return data by default is the second entry of "modifiedProperties". Is there a way to change this behavior?
In addition, can you share the document you found relate to "taragetResources"? The MS one I found does not go into much details. 
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/directoryaudit_get

Comment: ignore the document bit. Obviously I didnt click the link in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by putting the "modifiedProperties" section into a hashtable (Didn't do this properly last time). I use a function to convert the JSON result to Hashtable. The function code is copied from [here](https://4sysops.com/archives/convert-json-to-a-powershell-hash-table/).

```
Function ConvertTo-Hashtable {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType('hashtable')]
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        $InputObject
    )

process {
    ## Return null if the input is null. This can happen when calling the function
    ## recursively and a property is null
    if ($null -eq $InputObject) {
        return $null
    }

    ## Check if the input is an array or collection. If so, we also need to convert
    ## those types into hash tables as well. This function will convert all child
    ## objects into hash tables (if applicable)
    if ($InputObject -is [System.Collections.IEnumerable] -and $InputObject -isnot [string]) {
        $collection = @(
            foreach ($object in $InputObject) {
                ConvertTo-Hashtable -InputObject $object
            }
        )

        ## Return the array but don't enumerate it because the object may be pretty complex
        Write-Output -NoEnumerate $collection
    } elseif ($InputObject -is [psobject]) { ## If the object has properties that need enumeration
        ## Convert it to its own hash table and return it
        $hash = @{}
        foreach ($property in $InputObject.PSObject.Properties) {
            $hash[$property.Name] = ConvertTo-Hashtable -InputObject $property.Value
        }
        $hash
    } else {
        ## If the object isn't an array, collection, or other object, it's already a hash table
        ## So just return it.
        $InputObject
    }
  }
}

$hashtable1 = @{}
$hashtable2 = @{}
$hashtable1 = Get-aAuditEvent -Tenant "contoso.onmicrosoft.com"|ConvertFrom-Json|ConvertTo-HashTable
$hashtable2 = $hashtable1.targetResources.modifiedProperties
$hashtable2[0].displayName
$hashtable2[0].oldValue
$hashtable2[0].newValue
```

The output of the code is below. I still need to workout how to parse "newValue" properly. But at least I can show what actions have been done and what have been changed.

```
AssignedLicense
[]
["[SkuName=ENTERPRISEPACK, AccountId=cdc4b90d-7fa9-4a12-8d58-c2872266673c, SkuId=6fd2c87f-b296-42f0-b197-1e91e994b900, DisabledPlans=[]]"]
```